# Updating data automatically using Cloud Firestore Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, crud

Is there a way to update or create a new document in the Cloud Firestore database, automatically after a period of time?
I hope to find a document that describes how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to write a firebase function.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions